# Что такое «недопустимая-метка»

Tags: обсуждение, faq, метки

Метки [русский-язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba), [язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba), [русский](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9) и др. (полный список [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/tags/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0/synonyms)) никак не помогают узнать, с чем связан вопрос и к какому разделу языка он относится (сайт и так посвящен вопросам, связанным с русским языком; другие вопросы на нем — офтопик), поэтому автоматически заменяются на [недопустимая-метка](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0).

Если вы увидите, что в заданном вопросе содержится [недопустимая-метка](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0), пожалуйста, измените ее на подходящую.

Если, по вашему мнению, есть еще бесполезные метки, пожалуйста, укажите их в ответе.